# Login required before review

Tags: product, customer, review

I have noticed that sometimes, even when I am logged in and want to review a product on my magento website, it asks me to log in. and this must have in one way or the other frustrated some of my website's users from leaving their review.

Does anyone knows what the cause may be and how I can rectify the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Magento have facility to *Disallow Write Reviews for guest customer means not logged in customer*

SO ,just need to go  `admin>System>Configuration>Catalog>Product Reviews>Allow Guests to Write Reviews`*=Make it No*

Comment: Thank you Amit, That option is already set to No. Guests can't review except they are logged in, But at times if they are logged in, it asks them to re-login again before they can make a review. Thats the issue